# Reset button for flexdashboard in R

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I have developed a flexdashboard in R. I have three drop down menu as input for the dashboard. Based upon the input to these drop down menu the dashboard changes accordingly.

Right, i need a reset button to reset my inputs in drop down menu to default values.

Any input is appreciated.

Regards,

Mohan

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can set up `input$reset` to act as a reset button.

First you need the input on your sidebar:

`selectizeInput("input_name", "My Input", c("Choose one" = "", c("Option 1","Option 2")))`

Then set up the reset button UI:

`actionButton("reset", "Reset Inputs")`

Finally, set up an observer tied to the reset button that changes the inputs back to default (or whatever you specify):

`observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateSelectizeInput("input_name", "My Input", c("Choose one" = "", c("Option 1","Option 2")))
}`

You can put all of this in your sidebar in flexdashboard. I hope this was helpful.